# Container goes out of jumbotron

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a problem with my website, when I'm creating new element based on `jumbotron`. Above a certain height, `container` (main view in my element), goes out from `jumbotron`, and I haven't got any idea, what I did bad. Excluding Bootstrap, I'm using [nk-o/jarallax](https://github.com/nk-o/jarallax).

HTML:

```html
<div class="jumbotron footer--jumbotron rounded-0">
    <div class="jarallax" style="background-image: url('/assets/newsletter.jpg');">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-left-align slogan">
                    <h2 class="slogan">Slogan</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6 col-right-align">
                    <div class="card newsletter bg-light rounded-0">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>

                            <div class="newsletter-pane">
                                <form>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" id="newsletterName" class="form-control rounded-0" placeholder="Twoje imię" required>
                                        <input type="email" id="newsletterEmail" class="form-control rounded-0" placeholder="Adres e-mail" required>
                                    </div>

                                    <button type="submit" class="btn bg-red rounded-0">Send</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>

                            <p class="card-description">Some text</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS for `jumbotron`:

```css
.jumbotron {
    background-color: #db1a1a;
}

.jumbotron.footer--jumbotron,
.jumbotron .footer--jumbotron {
    height: 70vh;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 1199.98px) {
    .jumbotron {
        padding: 0 !important;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .jumbotron {
        padding: 1rem 1rem;
    }
}

.jarallax {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}

.jarallax .jarallax-img {
    position: absolute;
    object-fit: cover;
    font-family: 'object-fit: cover;';
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}

.jumbotron.jarallax,
.jumbotron .jarallax {
    height: 100%;
}

.jumbotron.jarallax .container,
.jumbotron .jarallax .container {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .jarallax .col-lg-6.col-left-align {
        text-align: left;
    }

    .jarallax .col-lg-6.col-right-align {
        text-align: right;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1199.98px) {
    .jarallax .col-lg-6.col-left-align {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .jarallax .col-lg-6.col-right-align {
        text-align: center;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
    .jarallax .col-lg-6 {
        margin-left: 2rem;
        margin-right: 2rem;
    }

    .jarallax .col-lg-6 + .col-lg-6 {
        padding-top: 2rem;
        padding-right: 2rem;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .jarallax .col-lg-6 {
        padding-left: 2rem;
        padding-right: 2rem;
    }
}
```

Image:
[image]

Thanks a lot for any help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to replicate your problem [here in codepen](https://codepen.io/juanmnl/pen/wvKaLNm?editors=1100).

The jumbotron container is a fixed height (70vh) and the child elements, like the form are fixed too, so at some point things will overflow.

```css
.jumbotron.footer--jumbotron,
.jumbotron .footer--jumbotron {
    height: 70vh;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Quick fix will be to turn the parent container into a `display: flex;` then give the jumbotron `flex: 8` and the footer `flex:2` (or even better using `grid`)

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron"></div>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.footer {
  flex: 2;
  widht: 100%;
}

.jumbotron {
  background-color: #db1a1a;
```